# Using GPU cores for parallel computing in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on tensorflow-gpu and pyqt5 for an object detection system.

I have developed a project based on neural network model which is trained
by tensorflow and it is good but I need to speed up the detection rate.

My GPU is GTX 1060 and CPU is Corei7.

How can I use CUDA cores to divide my computations ?

I have searched a lot of articles and I have asked it several times in
*stack** overflow* but there is no response.

How can I use tensorflow-gpu with programming CUDA cores by libraries like
PYCUDA or numba or CUPY?

I have asked this question in several manners but I am looking for a right approach to use CUDA for programming GPU cores( GTX1060 has 1280 CUDA cores but Corei7 has 8 core and by giving computations to GPU , program will speed up in a large scale)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) for installation of tensorflow-gpu. 
In a script, tensorflow automatically uses GPU if available, but you can check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu) for more information to check the number of available cores or select some manually etc

Comment: thanks for your reply but the link you have inserted is about how tensorflow can work with more than one GPU , not about how each GPU cores can work with tensorflow.